# Call class backward variable (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, class

I have this fallowing code:

```
the_class = {
 second_class : {
  third_class : {
   first_variable_name : "third class first variable",
   fourth_class : {
    first_variable_name : "forth class first variable",
    first_function_name : function()
    {
    var out = "";
    out += the_class.second_class.third_class.first_variable_name + "\n";
    out += this.first_variable_name + "\n";
    return out;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

result = the_class.second_class.third_class.fourth_class.first_function_name();
alert(result);
```

Result:

```
third class first variable
forth class first variable
```

And i need call class variable who is in lower class location. So i using:
the_class.second_class.third_class.first_variable_name, but this is to long! :(

Are any options how i can call backward class location with same thing like this.variable?
I tried back.first_variable_name, backward.first_variable_name and no one working... :(

Same as in documents: ../../../folder_name/file_name.txt

Comment: If object X contains object Y, there's no direct way to reference X from inside Y.

Answer (score 0):

You could add references to each object's parent. This would allow you to do what you want:

```js
Myfourthclass = function(parentobj) {
    this.parent = parentobj;
    this.first_variable_name = "forth class first variable";
    
    var _this = this;
    this.first_function_name = function(){
        return _this.parent.first_variable_name + "\n" +
            _this.first_variable_name + "\n";
    }
}

Mythirdclass = function(parentobj) {
    this.parent = parentobj;
    this.first_variable_name = "third class first variable";
    this.fourth_class = new Myfourthclass(this);
}

Mysecondclass = function(parentobj) {
    this.parent = parentobj;
    this.third_class = new Mythirdclass(this);
}

Myfirstclass = function(){
    this.second_class = new Mysecondclass(this);
}

newclass = new Myfirstclass();
alert(newclass.second_class.third_class.fourth_class.first_function_name());
```